# Ruby Rails 2.3.5 Flash Hanging Around

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been doing a ton of reading on the way that flash[]= works in rails and understand that when you redirect_to, to use the flash[...]=..., and if you are rendering the action after assignment, then flash.now[...]...; however, my application's flash is persisting indefinitely, never actually going away during the session.

This question is a hypothetical.  If I have a controller,

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if my_cond 
      flash.now[:notice] = "Your condition is true"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Your condition isn't true"
      redirect_to some_other_rendering_action
    end
  end
end
```

If I redirect this time, then the next time I redirect, let's say via clicking a link that connects to some action that redirects to another render, but leaves flash unmodified, then it renders the flash.  The problem is this happens indefinitely, doesn't even end after one redirect.

How would you suggest troubleshooting this issue?  The application is probably 35k lines, and already has been washed to follow the flash and flash.now solution recommendations posted everywhere, so where do we look?

rails 2.3.5 high volume site, apache/mongrel

ADDING INFORMATION:

The flash is persisting in the session as well.

```
flash: !map:ActionController::Flash::FlashHash 
  :notice: You must be signed in to view this page.
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking for `flash.keep` calls and if you have no luck and want to get rid of the behavior, add an after_filter that calls `flash.discard` to your `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  after_filter :discard_flash
  private
  def discard_flash
    flash.discard
  end
end
```

Comment: I looked for keep calls and ruled them out as none of them were getting hit.  I then added an after filter as you suggest and again, no go.  I actually raise directly AFTER the discard, here:   def discard_flash
    flash.discard
    raise flash.to_yaml
  end
Following this, I attempt to reload or browse around a bit and get this on the next page.--- !map:ActionController::Flash::FlashHash 
:notice: You must be signed in to view this page.

Comment: Doesn't look like the flash you were setting there - find the source of that flash and you find your culprit. Make sure to check plugins and gems as well.

Comment: Turns out there was an error in the merge feature of memcached, we monkey patched the feature and it fixed the errors.  This was not the most current version, and I assume it's been fixed since then, so cheers! Happy coding.

Comment: +1, but I think "flash.discard if @performed_render" would be preferrable; otherwise you lose the flash on a redirection when it has never been displayed yet.